# Julia generates same code but need different time to execute

Tags: performance, julia

During an evaluation of an other question I stumple over a case where two different julia programms generate the same code but need different time to execute.

```
using BenchmarkTools
test(n) = [g() for i = 1:n]
```

Case 1:

```
g() = 0;
@btime test(1000);
```

1.020 μs (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)

Code 1:

```
code_native(g,())

    .text
Filename: In[2]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopl    (%rax,%rax)

@code_native test(1000)

    .text
Filename: In[1]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 2
    subq    $16, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    cmovnsq %rdi, %rax
    movq    $1, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movabsq $collect, %rax
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Case 2:

```
g() = UInt8(0);
@btime test(1000);
```

142.603 ns (1 allocation: 1.06 KiB)

Code 2:

```
code_native(g,())

.text
Filename: In[8]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 1
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopl    (%rax,%rax)

 @code_native test(1000)

    .text
Filename: In[11]
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Source line: 2
    subq    $16, %rsp
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    testq   %rdi, %rdi
    cmovnsq %rdi, %rax
    movq    $1, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movabsq $collect, %rax
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   *%rax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    nopw    %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Different timings but same code sounds very weird to me. Could someone explain what happens here?

Comment: Perhaps in case 2 it wasn't `test(1000)`.

Comment: ...or it was `UInt8` instead of `UInt`

Comment: Your are right. It should by a "byte" UInt8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time difference is unrelated to the different function `g()` used each time, but to the amount of memory zeroed as a result.

In case 1, 8 bytes * 1000 = 8000 bytes need to be allocated and zeroed.

In case 2, 1 bytes * 1000 = 1000 bytes need to be allocated and zeroed.

This can be seen from the results of `@btime`. In a clearer example, we have:

```
julia> @btime zeros(1000);
  767.300 ns (1 allocation: 7.94 KiB)

julia> @btime zeros(125);
  128.849 ns (1 allocation: 1.06 KiB)
```

Where `zeros(n)` simply returns an array of `n` Int zeroes. Notice the amount allocated matches the amounts in the question.

**UPDATE**

Stefan pointed out that, curiously, the output of `@code_native` for both `g()` and `test(Int)` is the same in both runs. Which begs the question how the computer knows if it is allocating UInt8s or Ints?

Since `g()` is redefined and `test(Int)` depends on it, the 0.5/0.6 introduced world age mechanism for dealing with redefinitions, triggers a recompilation of `test(Int)` when invoked after the redefinition. The new `test(Int)` has a similar `@code_native` (on an x86 target machine), but a reference to a `$collect` value is different in the two compilations. To clear this up, the `@code_llvm` output shows a difference in a suffix between the versions:

```
define %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* @julia_test_62122(i64) #0 !dbg !5 {
top:
  :
  :
  %5 = call %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* @julia_collect_62123(%Generator addrspace(11)* nocapture readonly %4)
  ret %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* %5
}
```

vs.

```
define %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* @julia_test_62151(i64) #0 !dbg !5 {
top:
  :
  :
  %5 = call %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* @julia_collect_62152(%Generator addrspace(11)* nocapture readonly %4)
  ret %jl_value_t addrspace(10)* %5
}
```

A closer to the metal approach would dig out the machine code for the two versions:

> 0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xe5, 0x48, 0x8b, 0x06, 0x48, 0x8b, 0x38, 0x48,
>   0xb8, **0xa0, 0x52,** 0xa1, 0x21, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xd0,
>   0x5d, 0xc3

vs.

> 0x55, 0x48, 0x89, 0xe5, 0x48, 0x8b, 0x06, 0x48, 0x8b, 0x38, 0x48,
>   0xb8, **0x10, 0x58,** 0xa1, 0x21, 0x7e, 0x7e, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xd0,
>   0x5d, 0xc3

Note 0xc3 is the x86 opcode for `ret` instruction. To get at the machine code, you need to go through the rabbit hole of the `methods(test)` nested objects/arrays.

Comment: The code of g() is in both cases the same. It clears 64bit register eax. Where is the code which allocate different amounts?

Comment: It is in `test(n)`. Which is natural, because you need to know `n`

Comment: n is in both cases 1000 ??

Comment: Also, you can use the macros `@code_native` and `@code_llvm` to look at code as in `@code_native test(1000)`.

Comment: `n` is a 1000, but the compiler doesn't know this, as `test(n)` has `n` as a parameter, and must compile `test(n)` for any `n`. Look at output of  `@code_native test(1000)`

Comment: code_native reports in both cases the same for test() and g(). Allocations and timing is different. What causes the difference?

Comment: You are right! code_native does output the same for both version of test, but it is not actually the same code. If you examine the code (on an i86 target) closely, there is a call to an address in `rax` which is loaded with `$collect`. Although the display is the same, it is a different `$collect` address and a different `test()` machine code. The compiler has a new version each time `g()` is redefined (related to world age concept). But these are the implementation internals. The obvious (and simple) picture is a difference of memory sizes.

Comment: OK, this explains the difference. $collect contains the knowledge to use either Int64 or UInt8. Your comment is the accepted answer.

Comment: @stefanbachert Look at the update in the answer... and also accept the answer in Stack Overflow